# QuickSight Row Level Security: DatasetRulesUnexpectedError

Tags: security, amazon-quicksight, row-level-security

I'm attempting to apply row-level security I have an S3-based dataset with username and what I want to filter on. The dataset looks good in quicksight. I can create an analysis on it. rls_rater_action_username maps to a column in my dataset. However, no matter what I do with this file I get the error "An unexpected error occurred. If this problem continues, contact your administrator. Error code: DatasetRulesUnexpectedError".

**csv file contents:**
username,rls_rater_action_username
Dave, test

The error is kind of useless. I have no idea what the issue is? Anyone have any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Usernames are case sensitive, write it exactly as amazon suggests with an uppercase Username.

Make sure the data type of both `datasets(dataset,rules dataset)`, are strings, that the filter will apply.

Column order also matters in your `s3` rules dataset.